# Contraseña para el usuario del sistema windows en postgres

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, windows

Estoy tratando de conectarme a una `Base de Datos` en `PostgresSql` desde aplicación hecha en `node js`, la aplicación la he desarrollado en un entorno `Linux`, sin embargo el probelma surgió al tratar de correrla en `Windows`. He instalado postgres en `Windows`, y tengo conexión con el `cliente` para Bases de Datos que uso. Sin embargo al intentar usar el comando `psql` en la consola, me produce el siguiente problema:

```
contraseña para el usuario RWI:
```

El error que se me muestra al tratar de correr mi aplicación con `pnpm run`:

```
error: la autentificación password falló para el usuario RWI
```

Para aclarar he instalado `postgres` y el usuario por defecto es el que uso. En ningún momento he creado el usuario RWI, que es el nombre del usuario de mi sesión de windows y no tiene contraseña de acceso.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, puedes crear una variable de entorno que se llame `PGUSER` y tenga como valor el usuario que quieres usar? No recuerdo si había que cambiar algo más en la configuración...